# Plotly DASH Python : The 'value' property is a number and may be specified as: - An int or float

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am having a problem with a plotly graph_objs.

I am trying to make a dash to visualize data while specifing values:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('nps-indicator', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown-id', 'value')
)

def indicator_func(selected_month):
    filtered_df = df[df['Mês pesquisa'].isin(selected_month)]
    a = filtered_df['NPS']
    figScore = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
      `mode="gauge+number+delta",
    value=[int(nps_calculate(a))],
    title={'text': "NPS Score"},
    domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    ))
    figScore.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='#001122', paper_bgcolor='#001122')

return figScore
```

The 'value' property is a number and may be specified as:
- An int or float

I get this error and i dont know why.. Could someone please help me find out what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is your desired output and what does your DataFrame look like? Your code isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) right now

Comment: Im sorry, this is my first post i am not so good at it... Basically i am doing a DASH in PYTHON using plotly and Dash modules.
I need to select the month value and return an AVERAGE of the value.

Im using an excel archive, as dataframe and im calculating it depending the values which are selected.

Answer (score 0):

`value=[int(nps_calculate(a))]`
here, value needs to an integer or a float but you are supplying a list.
`value=int(nps_calculate(a))`

Comment: So.. Let me update you guys.. This is my first Question here. I am still getting used to it. Basically my problem is display the graph in the photo depending the value the user input on the right side of the photo. For this i need to create a function. Using @app.callback(Output, Input)
def function_one(value):
>...
And my problem is that i cant display the graph with the value i want, dont know why...

Comment: did you apply the above suggestion?

Comment: Yes.. i does not work. I guess it is because i cant display the graphic object in an app callback function... If i display the graph outside the app.callback. it works almost fine...

Comment: https://github.com/Felippefn/dash-cx/blob/main/app.py here is the code if you want to check... My problem is with the `figScore`

Comment: in first glance, I can see you are returning None for this callback: https://github.com/Felippefn/dash-cx/blob/main/app.py#L302, maybe this is one of the issues. If its possible for you to share the data as well, I'd be happy to help. You can push it to GitHub maybe. I'll pull it from there..